# Nested foreach loop in Angular

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I have two arrays like this:

```
var obj1 = [{'target_object_id': 1, 'extra': 'ok'}, {'target_object_id': 2, 'extra': 'ok'}]

var obj2 = [{'id': 4}, {'id': 2}]
```

What I want to do is loop through `obj1` and `obj2` and

```
if obj1.target_object_id == obj2.id // Append obj2['extra']=obj.extra
```

How to do this in angular?

Answer (score 8):

This would be with angular :

```
angular.forEach(obj1, function(item1) {
   angular.forEach(obj2, function(item2) {
    if(item1.target_object_id===item2.id) {
           item2.extra = item1.extra; // change it as you wish
           // some code
     }
   });
});
```